# Swift: Passing Parse ObjectIDs Between Multiple Controllers

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've got an app the uses multiple view controllers to read / edit / save the same Parse object. Since each view controller edits the object, I load the object when the view loads and save right before going to the next view controller. Everything works perfectly except getting the ObjectID from one view controller to the next.

I was using NSUserDefaults, but as many others found, it causes crashes when jumping between view controllers. I've been messing with using prepareForSegue, but with so many view controllers, that could get very cumbersome, very quickly.

Anyone have any good ideas for passing that snippet of data? Is prepareForSegue the best way?

Comment: Yes, use `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Also, it is typically better to pass the **object** rather than the objectID.  With Parse you can simply assign an object instance to a relation or pointer attribute and the Parse framework will take care of the rest.  You generally never need to worry about the objectID.  Passing the object will also reduce the number of times you need to fetch and update the object and therefore reduce network traffic and API calls

Comment: @Paulw11 I think that's the way to go. I'm still new to Swift (and coding in general). Relation or pointer attribute - is that using core data? Is there one that would be easier (relation or pointer attribute) for me to use than the other? Thanks!

Comment: While you can assign an NSManagedObject instance to a relation attribute in Core Data in this case I was referring to PFObjects in Parse